# Creating callback via trait objects

Tags: rust

I am not sure exactly what I need hence the slightly vague wording.

Background: I am porting a C++ PDP11 emulator to rust and I am now implementing the memory mapped IO. Each device registers itself as responding to a set of addresses on the bus. Each device implementation provides a setter and a getter function to call to service a given address. A device can provide multiple. I have this so far.

```rust
use crate::common::*;
mod sysdev;

pub trait Device{
    fn get_device_map(&self) -> Vec<DeviceMapping>;
    fn reset(&mut self);
    fn interrupt_ack(&mut self, slot: u32);
    fn should_trace(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct DeviceMapping {
    pub addr: Word,
    pub setter: fn(&mut dyn Device, val: Word),
    pub getter: fn(&mut dyn Device) -> Word
}
```

as you see a device must implement the get_device_map function that returns a list of addresses and callbacks.

My first device (a very simple one)

```rust
use crate::devices::*;

struct SysDevices {}

impl SysDevices{
    pub fn get_psw(&mut self) -> Word{
        42
    }
    pub fn set_psw(&mut self, val:Word){
    }
}

impl Device for SysDevices{
    fn get_device_map(&self) -> Vec<DeviceMapping>{

        let psw = DeviceMapping {
            addr: 0o177776,
            getter: Self::get_psw,
            setter: Self::set_psw
        }

        return vec![psw];
    }
    fn reset(&mut self){}
    fn interrupt_ack(&mut self, slot:u32){}
    fn should_trace(&self) -> bool{true}

}
```

this does not compile.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\devices\sysdev.rs:19:21
   |
19 |             getter: Self::get_psw,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn devices::Device`, found struct `devices::sysdev::SysDevices`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r mut (dyn devices::Device + 'r)) -> _`
                 found fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r mut devices::sysdev::SysDevices) -> _ {devices::sysdev::SysDevices::get_psw}`
```

It seems to be saying that I am supplying a concrete object rather than a trait object. What piece of rust magic am I missing? Maybe the definitions of setter and getter are wrong, I say they are fn that take a Device object which seems correct.

EDIT: Added thye glue code that holds these together

an instance of bus manages all the devices and owns the ram too

```
pub struct Bus {
    pub ram: Memory,
    devices:Vec<Box<ConnectedDevice>>,
    devmap:[u8;4096],
}
pub struct ConnectedDevice{
    pub vector:Word,
    pub device:Box<dyn Device>,
    pub regmap:Vec<DeviceMapping>
}
```

the devmap is a big array with a index at every possible address , 0 means no device, non zero is the index in the devices vec of the attached device. (A zero entry is hard coded in)

at startup attach_device is called for each device

```
pub fn attach_device(&mut self, device:Box<dyn Device>) -> Result<(), Exception>{
    let idx = self.devices.len() as u8;
    let map = device.get_device_map();
    let dev = Box::new(ConnectedDevice{
        regmap:map,
        vector:0,
        device,


    });
    self.devices.push(dev);
    for reg in &self.devices[idx as usize].regmap{
        self.devmap[reg.addr as usize] = idx;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

at run time when a word is read we go here (still in bus)

```
pub fn get_word(&mut self, addr: Word) -> Result<Word, Exception> {
    if addr > self.ram.size as u16 {
        if addr >= DEVICE_BASE_ADDR {
            let dev = self.get_device(addr)?;
            let x = dev.regmap.iter().find(|x| x.addr == addr).unwrap();
            let w = (x.getter)(&mut *dev.device);
            Ok(w)
        } else {
            throw!(ExceptionType::NoRam)
        }
    } else {
        Ok(self.ram.get_word(addr))
    }
}

fn get_device(&mut self, addr:Word) -> Result<&mut ConnectedDevice, Exception>{
    let off = addr - DEVICE_BASE_ADDR;
    let idxb = self.devmap[(off / 2) as usize];
    if idxb == 0{
        throw!(ExceptionType::DeadDevice); // no device mapped here
    }
    return Ok(&mut self.devices[idxb as usize]);
}
```

this end up calling the getter

Comment: How do you intend to call the setter and getter? The problem is you can't prove that the device supplied when the getter is called is the same as the one the device mapping is implemented for. It might be more appropriate to implement DeviceMapping as a generic trait.

Comment: @user1937198 I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for your specific application, but I feel I should point out that a trait could be used given the code shared so far.

```rust
pub trait Mapping {
    const address: usize;
    
    fn get(&mut self) -> Word;
    fn set(&mut self, val: Word);
}

impl Mapping for SysDevices {
    const address: usize = 0o177776;
    
    fn get(&mut self) -> Word {
        42
    }
    
    fn set(&mut self, val: Word) {
        // Register magic
    }
}
```

Also, are you sure it that the getter and setter could actually accept any `&mut dyn Device` and still function correctly? It looks to me like it must accept accept `&mut Self`.

```rust
pub trait Device: Sized {
    fn get_device_map(&self) -> Vec<DeviceMapping<Self>>;
    fn reset(&mut self);
    fn interrupt_ack(&mut self, slot: u32);
    fn should_trace(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct DeviceMapping<T> {
    pub addr: Word,

    // Functions could be dynamically sized closures that mutate their contents so I
    // switched it to FnMut. If it truly is just a regular function, then a trait like
    // above may be better suited to this.
    pub setter: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut T, Word)>,
    pub getter: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut T) -> Word>,
}

impl Device for SysDevices {
    fn get_device_map(&self) -> Vec<DeviceMapping<Self>> {
        let psw = DeviceMapping {
            addr: 0o177776,
            getter: Box::new(Self::get_psw),
            setter: Box::new(Self::set_psw),
        };

        return vec![psw];
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: a device registers multiple mappings, so the first one for sure cant work as I would need 2 different impl Mapping for Sysdevice (my example just shows the first one). Otherwise I have to split the device up into different objects (which simply is too complex for things like disk drives that have lots of coordinated registers ocntrolling their behavior

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be to make the device a type parameter of your `DeviceMapping` struct  and your `ConnectedDevice` struct:

```
pub struct DeviceMapping<T: Device> {
    pub addr: Word,
    pub setter: fn(&mut T, val: Word),
    pub getter: fn(&mut T) -> Word
}

struct ConnectedDevice<T: Device> {
    vector:Word,
    device: T,
    regmap:Vec<DeviceMapping<T>>
}
```

then add a new trait which `MappedDevice` implements which is generic over the device type to implement type erasure:

```
trait MappedDevice {
    fn get_word(&mut self, addr: Word) -> Word;
    // Whatever the corrisponding set function is
    fn set_word(&mut self, addr: Word) -> Word;
}

impl <T: Device> MappedDevice for ConnectedDevice<T> {
    fn get_word(&mut self, addr: Word) -> Word {
            let x = self.regmap.iter().find(|x| x.addr == addr).unwrap();
            (x.getter)(&mut self.device)
    }
    // Corrisponding set function impl goes here.
}
```

You can then call the traits methods from your get_word function.

Comment: as per my comments to the other answer this is not doable. A device can register multiple addresses, each with its own set and get function. In your design I would need 2 or more different impl of the trait. Also it cannot be generic, you cannot have a vector that contains DevMap<A> and Devmap<B>, I need dynamic dispatch

Comment: @pm100 This design is based around that constraint, you can register multiple instances of the DeviceMapping struct under the same device, they all go into the same ConnectedDevice struct which is aware of what the type of device is. You can't have a vec of `DeviceMapping<T>`, but that was specifically why I asked to see your calling code, in this design you have a vec of `dyn MappedDevice` which then contains a vec of `DeviceMapping<A>` for the device A.

Comment: The idea of this design is to move the polymorphism from the point of the callback, which is extremely messy to do safely, to device abstraction, so that the guarantee of what type of device is passed in is encoded in the typesystem.

Comment: I dont see where I put the meat of the device - could you edit to include  wiring up my SysDevices sample with 2 addresses

Comment: and I still dont see how I can have a lookup table of MappedDevice<T> where there are different Ts in the same vec

Comment: @pm100, my understanding is you don't, that you lookup by ConnectedDevice and then from there by mapping. if this is not true then the design would need to be redone.

Comment: for each io mapped address I have a byte thats an index into a table of devices. That index tells me which registered device will handle the request (or none if the idx is 0). This is my entry point to the whole thing. I receive a u16 as input from the Cpu, thats all.